# onPageScrollStateChanged(int state): what does state represent

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Whenever I set .registerOnPageChangeCallback on my viewpager 3 methods are called, one of them is onPageScrollStateChanged, I want to know what is the variable state represents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation:

> `public static final int SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`
>
> Indicates that the ViewPager2 is currently being dragged by the user,
>   or programmatically via fake drag functionality.
>
> Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
>
> `public static final int SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`
>
> Indicates that the ViewPager2 is in an idle, settled state. The
>   current page is fully in view and no animation is in progress.
>
> Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)
>
> `public static final int SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`
>
> Indicates that the ViewPager2 is in the process of settling to a final
>   position.
>
> Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)

For more check [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback)